# Does npm install mean the script only works with Node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, node.js, npm-install

I'm trying to use an API via it's helpfully developed JS SDK. So the SDK instructions on the GitHub page are to `npm install`. I'm wondering though, does this imply I have to have Node.js because the SDK has been written specifically for it, or if I just have basic vanilla JS/jQuery, can I just.... Copy the source code from GitHub into my scripts or use it some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the project is using npm to handle dependencies. It has a package.json file that stores what those dependencies are, and npm install will download them into a folder usually called 'node_modules.'

It's dependency management. It doesn't mean it's written for node, but that it uses node to download external dependencies.

Comment: Ah ok, so copy and pasting the code will fail because I won't grab the dependencies appropriately (unless I'm lucky enough that there are none or that they're already present), understanding that right?

Comment: The instructions on GitHub that says "npm install" is likely referring to how to set up an environment that runs the source code. You will not be able to run the application if it is missing dependencies. If you already have the dependencies, it will compare against the version listed in package.json. Are you using that API package as-is or are you making changes to the API package? If you're just using it as a dependency in your own project, the compiled/dist version should be available. You would only need to npm install if you wanted to run that package standalone.

Comment: Ah ok, so I want to use it in my own project, not standalone. So sounds like I should be able to copy and use the source code then?

Comment: Not the source code, but the dist version. Typically the source code still needs to be compiled. If you're going to compile it yourself, you follow the dev instructions. If you're using their compiled version, you should be able to pull it in according to what ever dependency management you're using for your own project.